# sklearn.KBinsDiscretizer return 0 for all bins

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have an narray of shape (1,188). Trying to create bins using KBinsDiscretizer but it gives me back only zeros annotated bins.

```
 # transform the dataset with KBinsDiscretizer
    enc = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=18, encode='ordinal' ,strategy='uniform')#strategy='uniorm'

    test =(np.asarray(list_event_MES).astype(np.float)).reshape(1, -1)
    print(test)
    print(test.shape)

    enc.fit(test)
    test2 = enc.transform(test)
    print(test2.tolist())
```

Will return zero for all bins.

> Matrice input :
>   [[0.13614053 0.14069501 0.08270327 0.26015096 0.15958708 0.16834299
>     0.14913976 0.11897561 0.23232807 0.0892398  0.1637264  0.17120459
>     0.19350733 0.18131615 0.20117186 0.1586006  0.19068352 0.24293008 . ....
>     0.2112216  0.21829195 0.28169516 0.27585681 0.27317305 0.1849694
>     0.23402622 0.24994829 0.20873297 0.25534803 0.15556027 0.27226802
>     0
>     0.14180543 0.24001428]]
>
> shape :
>   (1, 188)
>
> Warnings for the 188 columns :
>   /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_discretization.py:159: UserWarning: Feature 0 is constant and will be replaced with 0.
>     "replaced with 0." % jj)
>   /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_discretization.py:159: UserWarning: Feature 1 is constant and will be replaced with 0.
>     "replaced with 0." % jj)
>   /miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_discretization.py:159: UserWarning: Feature 2 is constant and will be replaced with 0.
>     "replaced with 0." % jj)

Comment: Hi @ZheFrench, if you feel that the below answer was appropriate kindly mark it as a verified answers so that it helps others who visit this in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the shape of your array `(1,188)`, we can infer that there is only `1` sample and `188` features. As per the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html#sklearn-preprocessing-kbinsdiscretizer) of`KBinsDiscretizer`, it is used for binning continuous data into intervals and it happens at a feature level, i.e. for each feature (or in other words for each column of your data) the `KBinsDiscretizer` computes the bin intervals and then bins your data, an example of which is shown below:

```
X = [[-2, 1, -4,   -1],
     [-1, 2, -3, -0.5],
     [ 0, 3, -2,  0.5],
     [ 1, 4, -1,    2]]
est = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode='ordinal', strategy='uniform')
est.fit(X)  

Xt = est.transform(X)
Xt  

array([[ 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      ​[ 1., 1., 1., 0.],
      ​[ 2., 2., 2., 1.],
      ​[ 2., 2., 2., 2.]
```

Here for each column the discretizer computes the bin intervals and bins them. In your case you just have one data point for each feature so computing bins doesn't make any sense. Instead, if your data is of shape `(188,1)` i.e. with `188` examples and `1` feature then it works perfect as shown below:

```
enc = KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=18, encode='ordinal' ,strategy='uniform')
list_event_MES = np.random.normal(0,2,188).reshape(-1,1)
test =(np.asarray(list_event_MES))
print(test.shape)
(188,1)

enc.fit(test)
test2 = enc.transform(test)

print(test2[0:5])

array([[12.],
   [12.],
   [ 7.],
   [ 9.],
   [ 3.]])
```